# Extract .tar.gz file that has files with .gz extension

Tags: windows, compression, zip, tar

Using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93139/can-i-zip-an-entire-folder-using-gzip) question I 'zipped' the folder with thousands of images on apache server. This apparently changed the files inside the folder itself and zipped the files. But that's not the issue atm.

I downloaded this `.tar.gz` file, and unpacked it with 7-zip, and got `.tar` file, which I then opened with 7-zip again and when I extracted it, but all the images inside still have `.gz` extension :\

Now there are over 9000 files (like literally, about 9400 files) with `.gz` extension that are useless to me. I cannot go and extract each one individually.

Is there a way to extract each image, and remove the `.gz` files in one go?

Thanks

Comment: Oh god I'm stupid! I can just select them all and extract with 7zip on right click (the one thing I didn't try)... You can close this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer in the end, was just to select all, and to right click on 7zip and select extract here.

And afterwards just delete `.gz` files.

Hennes gave really good answer too :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Easiest way (assuming no more than about 2000 files) is to use a wildcard: `gunzip *.gz`

If there are more files, or if you also have them in subdirs, try this:

```
find /path/to/files/ -name "*.gz" -exec gunzip {} +
```

The reason for that is that argument lists have limited space; `gunzip *.gz` will fail if you try it with too many files at once.

Find explanation:

```
find /path/to/files/   Finds all files in that path (and in subdirs)  
-name "*.gz"           Filter on name
-exec                  For each name execute a program.
{}                     The name of the program
+                      Feed the program as many arguments as possible in one go
                       (if you use ';', it will run gunzip once for each file).
```

If you have folders with names ending in `.gz`, too, you might want to add a `-type f` to have `find` only find regular files.